# Matching ng-model and ng-options with Angular

Tags: angularjs

in my controller I have a model and an array like this:

```
 $scope.myModel = {
   title:'title',
   descr:'descr',
   id: ''
 };

 $scope.arrayOption = [
   {id: 1, text:"aaaaaaa"},
   {id: 2, text:"bbbbbbb"}
 ];
```

In my html file I have this select input

```
  <select ng-model="myModel.id" ng-options="item.text for item in arrayOption"></select>
```

When i change the selected value, I would like update my model (myModel.id) with the value of id in arrayOption.

With the code above, the content of myModel.id is the entire object, not only the id field.

Can you help me, please?

Here's the 
[plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DqbpkUOV9jLxwjgZeiDL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution:

```
 <select ng-model="myModel.id" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in arrayOption"></select>
```

Works well! Here the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3L4AABzjvqzyow0u3koU?p=preview).

Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your ng-model binding to bind the selected value to the model directly, not a property thereof.

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="item.text for item in arrayOption">
</select>
```

See [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/woQ67o0ch3vn6rX9JbvZ?p=preview).

If that isn't what you wanted and you wanted to map both the id and the text, you should consider updating your arrayOptions from text to title to match the intended structure of your model.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.title for item in arrayOption track by item.id"
    ng-model="myModel">
</select>
```

Comment: In this way I loose the 'title' and 'desc' values from model. I would like the id in addition to them.

Comment: @robb my second option will allow you to preserve at least some of the data.  But if you want to do it this way, where you're mixing two different data structures, then you need a separate model altogether and you'll have to map it manually at some point to your title/desc model.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your model!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="plunker">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
          </head>

          <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

              {{myModel.title}}
              <br>
              {{myModel.descr}}
              <br>
              {{myModel.id}} <br>

              <select ng-change="change(temp)" ng-model="temp" ng-options="item.text for item in arrayOption"></select>

          </body>

        </html>
```

and JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myModel = {
    title:'title',
    descr:'descr',
    id: ''
  };

  $scope.arrayOption = [
    {id: 1, text:"aaaaaaa"},
    {id: 2, text:"bbbbbbb"}
  ];

  $scope.change = function(temp){
    $scope.myModel.id = temp.id;
  }

});
```

[Here Is Your Plnkr Solution!](https://plnkr.co/edit/LXDhjTsFClICX3bVEaNb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Or more easy !!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      {{myModel.title}}
      <br>
      {{myModel.descr}}
      <br>
      {{myModel.id}} <br>

      <select ng-change="myModel.id = temp.id" ng-model="temp" ng-options="item.text for item in arrayOption"></select>

  </body>

</html>
```